# compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions

Tags: numerical-methods, python

In the following code I have been able to:

1. Implement Gaussian elimination with no pivoting for a general square linear system.
2. I have tested it by solving Ax=b, where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.
3. I have compared my solution against the solution obtained using numpy.linalg.solve

However in the final task I need to compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions. I know the infinity norm is the greatest absolute row sum of a matrix. But how can I do this to compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions, my solution and the numpy.linalg.solve. Looking for some help with this!

```
import numpy as np
def GENP(A, b):
    '''
    Gaussian elimination with no pivoting.
    % input: A is an n x n nonsingular matrix
    %        b is an n x 1 vector
    % output: x is the solution of Ax=b.
    % post-condition: A and b have been modified. 
    '''
    n =  len(A)
    if b.size != n:
        raise ValueError("Invalid argument: incompatible sizes between A & b.", b.size, n)
    for pivot_row in range(n-1):
        for row in range(pivot_row+1, n):
            multiplier = A[row][pivot_row]/A[pivot_row][pivot_row]
            #the only one in this column since the rest are zero
            A[row][pivot_row] = multiplier
            for col in range(pivot_row + 1, n):
                A[row][col] = A[row][col] - multiplier*A[pivot_row][col]
            #Equation solution column
            b[row] = b[row] - multiplier*b[pivot_row]
    x = np.zeros(n)
    k = n-1
    x[k] = b[k]/A[k,k]
    while k >= 0:
        x[k] = (b[k] - np.dot(A[k,k+1:],x[k+1:]))/A[k,k]
        k = k-1
    return x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.round(np.random.rand(100, 100)*10)
    b =  np.round(np.random.rand(100)*10)
    print (GENP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b)))
```

for example this code gives the following output for task 1 listed above:

```
[-6.61537666  0.95704368  1.30101768 -3.69577873 -2.51427519 -4.56927017
 -1.61201589  2.88242622  1.67836096  2.18145556  2.60831672  0.08055869
 -2.39347903  2.19672137 -0.91609732 -1.17994959 -3.87309152 -2.53330865
  5.97476318  3.74687301  5.38585146 -2.71597978  2.0034079  -0.35045844
  0.43988439 -2.2623829  -1.82137544  3.20545721 -4.98871738 -6.94378666
 -6.5076601   3.28448129  3.42318453 -1.63900434  4.70352047 -4.12289961
 -0.79514656  3.09744616  2.96397264  2.60408589  2.38707091  8.72909353
 -1.33584905  1.30879264 -0.28008339  0.93560728 -1.40591226  1.31004142
 -1.43422946  0.41875924  3.28412668  3.82169545  1.96675247  2.76094378
 -0.90069455  1.3641636  -0.60520103  3.4814196  -1.43076816  5.01222382
  0.19160657  2.23163261  2.42183726 -0.52941262 -7.35597457 -3.41685057
 -0.24359225 -5.33856181 -1.41741354 -0.35654736 -1.71158503 -2.24469314
 -3.26453092  1.0932765   1.58333208  0.15567584  0.02793548  1.59561909
  0.31732915 -1.00695954  3.41663177 -4.06869021  3.74388762 -0.82868155
  1.49789582 -1.63559124  0.2741194  -1.11709237  1.97177449  0.66410154
  0.48397714 -1.96241854  0.34975886  1.3317751   2.25763568 -6.80055066
 -0.65903682 -1.07105965 -0.40211347 -0.30507635]
```

then for task two my code gives the following:

```
my_solution = GENP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b))
numpy_solution = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print(numpy_solution)
```

resulting in:

```
[-6.61537666  0.95704368  1.30101768 -3.69577873 -2.51427519 -4.56927017
-1.61201589  2.88242622  1.67836096  2.18145556  2.60831672  0.08055869
-2.39347903  2.19672137 -0.91609732 -1.17994959 -3.87309152 -2.53330865
 5.97476318  3.74687301  5.38585146 -2.71597978  2.0034079  -0.35045844
 0.43988439 -2.2623829  -1.82137544  3.20545721 -4.98871738 -6.94378666
-6.5076601   3.28448129  3.42318453 -1.63900434  4.70352047 -4.12289961
-0.79514656  3.09744616  2.96397264  2.60408589  2.38707091  8.72909353
-1.33584905  1.30879264 -0.28008339  0.93560728 -1.40591226  1.31004142
-1.43422946  0.41875924  3.28412668  3.82169545  1.96675247  2.76094378
 -0.90069455  1.3641636  -0.60520103  3.4814196  -1.43076816  5.01222382
 0.19160657  2.23163261  2.42183726 -0.52941262 -7.35597457 -3.41685057
-0.24359225 -5.33856181 -1.41741354 -0.35654736 -1.71158503 -2.24469314
-3.26453092  1.0932765   1.58333208  0.15567584  0.02793548  1.59561909
 0.31732915 -1.00695954  3.41663177 -4.06869021  3.74388762 -0.82868155
 1.49789582 -1.63559124  0.2741194  -1.11709237  1.97177449  0.66410154
 0.48397714 -1.96241854  0.34975886  1.3317751   2.25763568 -6.80055066
-0.65903682 -1.07105965 -0.40211347 -0.30507635]
```

finally for task 3:

```
if np.allclose(my_solution, numpy_solution):
    print("These solutions agree")
else:
   print("These solutions do not agree")
```

resulting in:

```
These solutions agree
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have some norm $||\cdot||$ then you also have a metric $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$ so if you're comparing to row reduced matrices $A$ and $A'$ it will be $||A-A'||$.

Comment: would you know how to program this?

Comment: why not divided by A?

Comment: @user104  In general division is not defined for vectors so you can't divide by them. You can think of a norm as an abstraction of length and a metric as an abstraction of distance in vector spaces. Also, the geometric meaning of vector subtraction gives us a geometric interpretation of $||x-y||$ as the distance between the heads of the two vectors.

Vector subtraction is pointwise meaning each entry subtracts from exactly the same entry in a matrix of the same size so $a_{ij}-a'_{ij}$ for each entry in the matrices $A$ and $A'$. Then take the norm once you've got the new matrix.